# How to register a wildcard url in Drupal with the hook_menu?

Tags: drupal, hook-menu

I'm starting to work with Drupal and I'm really confused as how to create a hook_menu function that allows you to register a URL with 1 or 2 different values, that can be hidden and not displayed in the breadcrumbs.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Even an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the breadcrumbs bit, but I think you're looking for wildcard (`%`) and auto-loader wildcard (`%mymodule_entity`) components in the path.

From the [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) page...

> Wildcards within paths also work with integer substitution. For example, your module could register path 'my-module/%/edit'. When path 'my-module/foo/edit' is requested, integer 1 will be replaced with 'foo' and passed to the callback function. Note that wildcards may not be used as the first component.

```
$items['my-module/%/edit'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_edit',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
);
```

> Registered paths may also contain special "auto-loader" wildcard components in the form of '%mymodule_abc', where the '%' part means that this path component is a wildcard, and the 'mymodule_abc' part defines the prefix for a load function, which here would be named mymodule_abc_load().

```
$items['my-module/%mymodule_abc/edit'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_edit',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
);
```